# Juno AppCenter 3.2.0 deb based updates ignored

Tags: release-juno, updates

The new AppCenter package for Juno, 3.2.0, which installed additional packages  for Flatpak, broke all contact with the DEB repos.  Updates that work fine with apt update/upgrade do not show up in AppCenter anymore- at all.  This happened in a VM and on physical hardware.